# Rails 3.2, Vagrant, and HAML: ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, vagrant

I've read every related topic that I can find on Stackoverflow and elsewhere and have not seen this specific issue reported.

One of my fellow developers is running Vagrant with an Ubuntu ocelot box on Windows 7. I'm on an iMac running Pow. We're developing a Rails app using HAML.

Once in a while, he will get this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Admin/apps#edit

Showing /vagrant/app/views/admin/_panel.html.haml where line #15 raised:

Missing partial admin/apps/list, application/list with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/vagrant/app/views"
```

I pull in the code and run it in Pow and it runs perfectly.

However, when he renames the offending file (say, from _list.html.haml to _kevin.html.haml), it starts working on his machine. If he renames it back to "_list" the error comes back.

It's not just a specific filename either. It's very random.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

It appears that this only happens when you attempt to load the view when it doesn't exist then go in and create it later. Vagrant/Rails seems to assume it doesn't exist still. Trying to figure out where this caching might occur and how we could clear that now.

**Edit 2**

It appears that restarting Vagrant fixes this issue.

```
vagrant reload
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: That's due to caching. I'm not specifically familiar with Vagrant, but most servers will cache in a Production environment. Try using the Development environment instead to prevent that. (I could be totally wrong, again, not familiar with Vagrant)

Comment: Thanks Kyle. We are running in development, not production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that restarting Vagrant fixes this issue.

```
vagrant reload
```

Hope this helps someone.